# how to connect couchdb with web api core

Tags: asp.net-core, couchdb, asp.net-core-webapi, couchdb-futon

want to connect  to a CouchDb databse from asp.net core web api , but am having trouble finding the code to do so.

Can anyone help me with the code to do that? What is the 'normal' way of doing that?

Cheers!

Comment: why noone is answering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the MyCouch Library for .Net https://github.com/danielwertheim/mycouch

Comment: You have more documentation in the project wiki https://github.com/danielwertheim/mycouch/wiki/documentation#install-using-nuget

Comment: not able to install  mycouch because some dependency is missing is theare any example with asp.net core 2.0 webapi crud with couch db so i can undertand basic operation step by step

Comment: Yo can check the cloudant web starter for ASP .NET https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/aspnet-core-cloudant. Cloudant is API level compatible with CouchDB

Comment: MyCouch has been updated to v5.1.1 @ 2018-03-19 working with net core 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same need and after evaluating the existing options, **I created a set of mechanisms that met the requirements that I had to meet and made available on github and the nuget package**.

The explanation of how to use it is on github.

Below is the link in case you want to take a look.

In time, to prevent someone from coming here and deleting my answer, I inform you that I have no intention of promoting what I did with this answer, just suggesting that you evaluate it and if it is your case, feel free to use it.

Link: [Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CouchDb.Repository.Helper/) |
[Github](https://github.com/wquintanilhadasilva/CouchDb.Repository)

An example webapi core project follows how to make this connection and perform data operations with this lib: [webapi core sample](https://github.com/wquintanilhadasilva/CouchDb.Repository/tree/master/samples/Apache.Couchdb.Helper.Sample/WebApplication)